# Test freezes when expect(result).toBe(null) fails test. (Angular 2, Jasmine)

Tags: angular, dom, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-ng-if

I have a test that checks if part DOM element has been removed by an ngIf. When I check the DOM using: `fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".button-area"))` the `result` is either `null` or a DOM element.

If the `result` is `null`, then the following test works fine. But, if the test `result` contains an element, it doesn't simply fail the test, it **freezes up** the browser.

The test looks like this:

```
var result = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".button-area"))
expect(result).toBe(null)
```

I have also tried `expect(result).toEqual(null)` and `.toBeFalsy()` which have the same result.

What is the proper way to test if a DOM element has been removed properly?

**UPDATE** 1/23/2017

I have found out this issue is specifc to the element returned by:

`fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".button-area"))`

This might be a **bug** with angular 2 or jasmine. If I use `document.getElementByClassName("button-area")` it is not an issue and the test works fine.

Comment: This is still an issue in June 2019

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since this seems to be a bug with Jasmine or Angular, here is a quick workaround if you are in a bind:

```
var result = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".button-area"))
expect(result === null).toBeTruthy()
```

You should expect to fix this in your own code when the issue is resolved.

Comment: Check this explanation about the issue: https://medium.com/@martatatiana/poor-detective-angular2-browser-crash-and-debugelement-f0a651dbf33
It seems that basically the error is produced when traversing debugElement as it has a huge tree of dependencies. So avoid huge objects in expect function argument.